# JSF SelectItems showing the order differently

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have JSF selectItems - in which there are list of descriptions which are in alphabatic order.

First it shows None and there are after remaining values.

We have added a new description starting with [ (open braces ). Now the thing is selectItem is taking this description as the first item and there after None is coming.

Can you please let me know the reason for this.

Thanks,
Adithya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show your code please